# Should I use an interface in this scenario

Tags: java, json, oop, interface, getter-setter

I am reading multiple differing json files from server which needs to be re-used again. Some of the json files are using the same tree structure.

To accomplish this task is this the best method -

Define an interface which has getter/setter methods from below json and then an implementing class which creates a new object based on json. Is creating an interface for this task overkill ?

```
{
"type":"test", 
"children":[
    {
    "id":testId,
    "type":"laptop",
    "price":"500",
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this would be overkill, if you are creating different objects and you are going to need the same attributes, then I would say this is the right approach.

You can also consider using a factory pattern.

Comment: Thanks, your answer led me to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708336/beginner-factory-pattern-in-java

Comment: You're welcome, that question has good information on the pattern that you can use.